# Calling specific element from array not returning (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I can't tell what's wrong with my code:

```
def morse_code(str)
    string = []
    string.push(str.split(' '))
    puts string
    puts string[2]
end
```

What I'm expecting is if I use "what is the dog" for str, I would get the following results:

```
=> ["what", "is", "the", "dog"]
=> "the"
```

But what I get instead is nil.  If I do string[0], it just gives me the entire string again.  Does the .split function not break them up into different elements?  If anyone could help, that would be great.  Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be :

```
def morse_code(str)
  string = []
  string.push(*str.split(' '))
  puts string
  p string[2]
end

morse_code("what is the dog" )
# >> what
# >> is
# >> the
# >> dog
# >> "the"
```

`str.split(' ')` is giving `["what", "is", "the", "dog"]`, and you are pushing this *array* object to the array *string*. Thus `string` became `[["what", "is", "the", "dog"]]`. Thus `string` is an array of size `1`. Thus if you want to access any index like `1`, `2` so on.., you will get `nil`. You can debug it using `p`(it calls `#inspect` on the array), BUT NOT `puts`.

```
def morse_code(str)
  string = []
  string.push(str.split(' '))
  p string
end

morse_code("what is the dog" )
# >> [["what", "is", "the", "dog"]]
```

With `Array`, `puts` works completely *different* way than `p`. I am not good to read MRI code always, thus I take a look at sometime *Rubinious* code. Look how they defined [`IO::puts`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/io.rb#L1776-L1803), which is same as *MRI*. Now look the [*specs for the code*](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/spec/ruby/core/io/puts_spec.rb#L57-L78)

```
it "flattens a nested array before writing it" do
    @io.should_receive(:write).with("1")
    @io.should_receive(:write).with("2")
    @io.should_receive(:write).with("3")
    @io.should_receive(:write).with("\n").exactly(3).times
    @io.puts([1, 2, [3]]).should == nil
  end

  it "writes nothing for an empty array" do
    x = []
    @io.should_receive(:write).exactly(0).times
    @io.puts(x).should == nil
  end

  it "writes [...] for a recursive array arg" do
    x = []
    x << 2 << x
    @io.should_receive(:write).with("2")
    @io.should_receive(:write).with("[...]")
    @io.should_receive(:write).with("\n").exactly(2).times
    @io.puts(x).should == nil
  end
```

We can now be sure that, [`IO::puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) or [`Kernel::puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) behaves with *array* just the way, as *Rubinious* people implemented it. You can now take a look at the MRI code also. I just found the *MRI* one, look [*the below test*](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/ruby/test_io.rb#L2225-L2234)

```
  def test_puts_recursive_array
    a = ["foo"]
    a << a
    pipe(proc do |w|
      w.puts a
      w.close
    end, proc do |r|
      assert_equal("foo\n[...]\n", r.read)
    end)
  end
```